# How to find if view of sun will be obstructed?

Tags: trigonometry

I know the following:

- My elevation ($4,000$ ft.)
- The mountain's elevation ($7,200$ ft.)
- The distance from me to the mountain ($2$ miles)
- The solar elevation ($38$)

How can I tell if the sun will be behind the mountain?

Comment: You might start by drawing a picture.

Comment: and converting miles to feet

Comment: Or feet to miles, if that floats your boat.  ;)

Comment: Solar elevation is 38 what?  Degrees?  You, the base of the mountain, and the peak, make three points of a a right triangle.  Is the angle of that triangle more less or equal to 38 degree?  If it's more, the sun in unobstructed.  If less the sun is obstructed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a picture that attempts to describe the situation:

[image]

The sun will be obscured by the peak if the angle of elevation to the peak $\beta$ is larger than the angle of elevation to the sun, which we know is $38^{\circ}$.  Otherwise, the sun will not be obscured.

We are given that the distance from You to $A$ is 2 miles, and that the difference in altitude from you to the peak is $7200-4000 = 3200$ feet.  Hence
$$ \tan(\beta) = \frac{\text{opp}}{\text{hyp}} = \frac{3200\text{ ft}}{2\text{ mi}} = \frac{3200\text{ ft}}{2\text{ mi}} \cdot \frac{1\text{ mi}}{5280\text{ ft}} \approx 0.30 $$
(note that the units cancel each other out---the tangent is a unitless quantity).  Then
$$ \beta \approx \arctan(0.30) \approx 17^\circ.$$
For those familiar with the unit circle and the difficulties of defining inverses of periodic functions, note that we are working exclusively in the first quadrant, thus the angle we want really is $\arctan(0.30)$, rather than this plus some integer multiple of $90^{\circ}$.

Therefore, since the angle to the peak (approx. $17^{\circ}$) is less than the angle to the sun ($38^{\circ}$), the peak will not obstruct the sun.

Comment: Good answer.  But maybe ... too much.  The question was how do I solve this, and maybe the helpful answer would be "with trigonometry".

Comment: Nice diagram, +1 ... did you use GeoGebra?

Comment: @fleablood Should the quality of the question dictate the quality of the answer?  If the question is so poorly posed that it deserves no answer (or a snarky answer), are there not tools here that allow for questions to be closed?

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee Yes, that is GeoGebra.

Comment: "Should the quality of the question dictate the quality of the answer?"  No, but the nature of the question can determine the nature of the answer.  A question of "how do I do this" is a legitimate question, but  "what is the answer" is not. How do I do this should be answered, more or less, as "set it up, look at what you know, observe what you need to do, and do it" and not "here, I did your homework for you".  My "use trigomometry" was not snark. It was a suggestion to solve the angle using trigonometry.  i.e. a short version of my comment above. which should be enough... at least to start.

Comment: Thank you for the thoughtful and thorough answer! Note, this was not a homework assignment but a real world example as I figure out viewing locations for the upcoming solar eclipse. Now I have the structure to understand and apply elsewhere.